# Quotient Property of Square Roots: why does GeoGebra seem not to care about it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic

I was arguing with my friend about the Quotient Property of Square Roots and it resulted in an exchange of results between my knowledge and WolframAlpha's, and that of GeoGebra; the latter "claims" that $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ [has a different domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAo38.png) than $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-4}}$, result that WolframAlpha [seems to disagree with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T17Tz.png) (note: I'm assuming a real domain).

From my point of view, the square root operator in $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-4}}$ is not applied to the entire fraction, but it's called instead for two instances separately, the numerator and the denominator. As a main reason for my argument, I thought about the most common order of operations, for which powers should be computed before multiplications, hence $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-4}}=\big(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-4}\big)^{1/2}=\frac{(x^2-1)^{1/2}}{(x^2-4)^{1/2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$.

However, if the operator is treated as a function that takes the entire fraction as an argument, this is not true anymore because a negative numerator and a negative denominator give still rise to a positive argument (hence a different domain).

My guess is, GeoGebra doesn't care about the arithmetic syntax, but it rather considers the code syntax as it possibly computes samples in a `function(argument)` fashion only. However, I am very confused, since unlike, say, MATLAB, this is a tool whose main purpose is to display an interpolated function in a graph, so I am too humble to take any conclusions.

What do you think, is GeoGebra the wrong one, at least from a mathematical point of view, or am I missing something? I'm really confused right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Mathematica is inconsistent between its analytics and its plotting routines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpwCW.png), and behind the scenes, WolframAlpha is using the core Mathematica language.  GeoGebra has the correct (or rather, standard) interpretation, which agrees with Mathematica's analytics.

Comment: @march Thank you for the comment! I'm a little confused; if WolframAlpha uses the Mathematica language, isn't it necessarily following the standard as well? This leads me to assume that the interpretation is not part of the standard (?), but GeoGebra's interpretation agrees with Mathematica's analytics, therefore the "right" result is that of the analytics/GeoGebra's representation? By the way, by analytics do you mean the algorithms and data obtained from an input?

Comment: I just mean that Mathematica has both algebraic (symbolic) computation and numerical computation.  It uses whatever algebraic/symbolic algorithms it uses to determine the domain of those functions (using `FunctionDomain`) on the reals, and it uses its *numerical* capabilities to plot the functions.  Apparently, those two things don't agree, *inside Mathematica*. And there's a reason for that: although the deep math eludes me, if you plot the real and imaginary parts of those functions as functions of $Re(x)$ and $Im(x)$, the functions along the real axis *essentially* coincide.

Comment: I see now, I had no idea of that. I always assumed symbolic and numerical coincided. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Here's a good example. Consider $x=0$. That's just not in the domain of $\sqrt{x^2-1}/\sqrt{x^2-4}$ when considered as a function of real numbers. However, *Mathematica* knows how to use complex numbers, and so it can easily plug in $x=0$ to both of these square roots, and it spits out the principle roots, which are $i$ for the numerator and $2i$ for the denominator. Thus, the quotient is 1/2. That's *also* what you get when you plug in $x=0$ to $\sqrt{(x^2-1)/(x^2-4)}$, and $x=0$ *is* in the domain of that function (thought of as a function of the reals).

Comment: It's strange though, since the symbolic result in WA seems to be still defined in R. I mean, the real part is 0 even when operating under C, but the number itself is (1/2,0) - how is it even considered, or plotted, in the real plane? The behaviour definitely makes sense now, or at least numerically. Should the numeric results be theoretically correct though? I mean, due to power properties, the two functions should be the same both numerically and theoretically, or am I wrong? I was expecting 1/2 in $$\sqrt{x^2-1}/\sqrt{x^2-4}$$ in C, but it's strange since I was expecting it in R as well.